# Defined Function Won't Print When I Try To Use It Again?

Tags: python, function

I have defined a function called `Start()` and I am finished with this function and I want to use it again it won't work. The first time it works but if I try to use this function again it won't work. Sorry if this question isn't clear.

```
import random

dice_numb = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

def Start():
    print("Hello Welcome To Dice Rolling")
    roll = input("\nWould You Like To Roll? Y/N: ")
    while roll != "Y":
        if roll == "Y":
            print("Alright")
            randomindex = random.randint(0,len(dice_numb)-1) 

            print (dice_numb[randomindex])

            break
        if roll == "N":
            print("Okay,Cya")
            sys.exit()

    again = input("Would You Like To Roll Again? Y/N: ")

    while again != "Y":
        if again == "Y":
            print("Alright,Lets Do It!")
        if again -- "N":
            print("Okay,Cya.")
            sys.exit()
Start()
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'using the function again'? In your code example, you only call your function once. And your function defines various states, where the whole application is shut down (`sys.exit()`), so nothing will happen after the application reaches one of these states.

Comment: How can this work? It would not enter the loop if you type "Y":   

    while roll != "Y":
        if roll == "Y":

Comment: Your code, as given, has an error: You have `if again -- "N":`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of Python :). I see a number of issues in your code:

Compare these changes to your code and read the comments:

```
import random

def Start():                                          
    print("Hello Welcome To Dice Rolling")
    roll = input("\nWould You Like To Roll? Y/N: ")

    while roll == "Y":
            print("Alright")
            dice_no = random.randint(0, 6)              # or random.randint(0, len(dice_numb) -1)  
            print(dice_no)                             # No need to index list

            roll = input("\nWould You Like To Roll Again? Y/N: ")
    else: 
        print("Okay,Cya")

Start()
```

*Note: don't start function names with capital letters, this naming convention is usually used for classes not functions.*

Comment: That is way better than the code in the question.  It can be improved though:  You can remove `if roll == 'N'` and unindent the `print` and `sys` lines so they are at the same level of `while`, with the same result.  One less line and easier to read.

Comment: Thank you, also any tips on defining functions? seems a bit confusing, because before I tried to re-use the function as previously stated nothing happened, what caused this? Thank you all so much :)

Comment: This code definitely shows how a program like this should work in the case where the user keeps entering 'Y'. If they enter something else, you only need the `print("Okay,Cya")` at the end of the function without the `else`, and no need for tests for 'N', nor the `sys.exit()`, nor then the `import sys`

Comment: @jberrio I apologize, I had changed the code, the previous one was not the one I meant to post. Sorry.

Comment: @xStrqfe Probably you added the second `Start` definition above the previous one in the source file. Remove the previous `Start` from the file and add the newer one. Plus, see the note I just placed now in my answer.

Comment: @direprobs Thank you, your code works very well. http://prntscr.com/ey8kmc

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this'll work or not; I'm also new to python. I think you forgot to import the "sys" module...

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
import random
import sys

dice_numb = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

def Start():
    print("Hello Welcome To Dice Rolling")
    roll = input("\nWould You Like To Roll? Y/N: ")
    if roll.upper() == "Y":
        print("Alright")

        print random.choice(dice_numb)
    if roll.upper() == "N":
        print("Okay,Cya")
        sys.exit()
    while 1:
        again =  input("Would You Like To Roll Again? Y/N: ")

        if again.upper() == "Y":
            print("Alright,Lets Do It!")
        if again.upper() == "N":
            print("Okay,Cya.")
            break
Start()
```

Comment: Thank you very much :), Also thank you for showing me how to make it non capital sensitive. If you don't mind me asking, how did you get the Start function to restart? The original code used the Function the same way but yet didn't work? Was it a problem with the while loop?

Comment: Your `while` loop could execute only if your `input` was different than `Y`.

Comment: This `while` loop runs until `input` is `n` or `N`.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much

Comment: At least upvote would be nice :)

Comment: I did, but not 15 reputation yet to make it count :/